# Getting error when run react-native run-android

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
     > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fbsdk'.
       > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-fbsdk:_debugPublishCopy'.
         > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
             file:/home/ubuntu/git/mstore-pro/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
           Required by:
             beostore:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified
         > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
             file:/home/ubuntu/git/mstore-pro/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
           Required by:
             beostore:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.46.4
         > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.1/support-annotations-27.0.1.pom
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.1/support-annotations-27.0.1.jar
             file:/home/ubuntu/git/mstore-pro/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.1/support-annotations-27.0.1.jar
           Required by:
             beostore:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0
         > Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.1/support-core-utils-27.0.1.pom
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.1/support-core-utils-27.0.1.jar
             file:/home/ubuntu/git/mstore-pro/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.1/support-core-utils-27.0.1.jar
           Required by:
             beostore:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0
         > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
             file:/home/ubuntu/git/mstore-pro/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
           Required by:
             beostore:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
         > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.1/cardview-v7-27.0.1.pom
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.1/cardview-v7-27.0.1.jar
             file:/home/ubuntu/git/mstore-pro/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.1/cardview-v7-27.0.1.jar
           Required by:
             beostore:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
         > Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.1/customtabs-27.0.1.pom
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.1/customtabs-27.0.1.jar
             file:/home/ubuntu/git/mstore-pro/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.1/customtabs-27.0.1.jar
           Required by:
             beostore:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
         > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom
             file:/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
             file:/home/ubuntu/git/mstore-pro/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
           Required by:
             beostore:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
```

compileSdkVersion 25

buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

targetSdkVersion 25

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've faced the same issue today.

Looks like there is some problem with `react-native-fbsdk` package;

I've found the only way to solve it for now:

at `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle`

change `compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+')`

to `compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0')`

**This is very bad solution.**

If you will find proper way to solve it - please share.

Comment: It worked for me, but I've changed to version 4.28.0. A good practice is always specif the library version instead of using the plus character.

Comment: Thanks to you I solved a one-week-end problem that was related to this issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer does the trick but a cleaner solution would be to restrict the android fbsdk version used in the react native fbsdk library. Adding the below code to project(root) build.gradle made sure that the specified version of fbsdk is used by all library projects.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah this works! In my first attempt, I placed it in the wrong build.gradle file. But once i placed it in the root build.gradle it worked.

Comment: Be sure you have the latest build gradle `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` otherwise it still might not work!

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue since this morning and as far as I can see it is a problem with the react-native-fbsdk library and android support repository.

If you go into any of the subfolders on the path where your sdk is installed (in your case) "home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support" you will probably see the "26.0.0-alpha1" as the last folder even though google (https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html - collapse com.android.support) clearly suggests the last folder should be "27.0.2"!

I have tried downloading the latest android_m2repository from the acquired link:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
but it is also missing all the following folders: 
26.0.0-beta1, 26.0.0-beta2, 26.0.0, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.1.0, 27.0.0, 27.0.1, 27.0.2

I managed to remove the error by editing node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle

compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0')

but am still not able to build and I am sure this is not the propper way to go even if you are able to build!

Answer (score 5):

Follow these Steps and Make your Build Successful

1. Go to Project `build.gradle file` adding `maven {url"https://maven.google.com"}` Will download the missing items .
2. `android/build.gradle file` and `restrict fbsdk Version to 4.28.0`.

**OTHER WAY**

Go to `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk` : `build.gradle` change to compileSdkVersion 26 or 27

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
                }
            }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Android studio solved this for me...

Below are the steps I followed

- Updated android-sdk(downloaded platform and build tools for version 27 and other auto suggests)
- Updated Android Studio
- Synced the dependency projects
- Android Studio automatically asked for updating gradle
- Running react-native run-android auto downloaded dependencies from gradle-4.1-all.zip which was auto added into my "gradle-wrapper.properties" file because of gradle update from the above step

Comment: updating android studio is not creting `/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/` folder for me

Comment: @Anantkamat Updated my exact steps. Hope that helps... BTW the appcompat-v7/27.0.1 folder is not added into my sdk as well... But I do not get the error anymore...