# React native-fbsdk unknown issue?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react native 0.49.5 and react 16.0.0-beta.5 for making an App.
I am using react native-fbsdk(^0.6.3) for facebook login. All necessary steps are taken to link android with the facebook sdk.
But When I ran `react-native run-android`, It threw an error.

Error log in CLI(TERMINAL):

> /home/sunny/projects/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
>
> /home/sunny/projects/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
>
> :react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.015 secs
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>   set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Here is my android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reactnativeapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-camera-kit')
    compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
      exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
    }
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

How can I solve this issue? Any help on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting error when run react-native run-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671206/getting-error-when-run-react-native-run-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like your issue was caused by new release [facebook-sdk-4.29.0](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/releases/tag/sdk-version-4.29.0) You need to limit this dependency by 4.28.0 version. The optimal solution would be to add to your `{project_root}/android/build.gradle`

```
def versionOverrides = [
  "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk": "4.28.0",
]

allprojects {
  /* your original repository dependencies here... */
  configurations.all {

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->

      def overrideVersion = versionOverrides[details.requested.group + ":" + details.requested.name]

      if (overrideVersion != null && details.requested.version != overrideVersion) {
        println("********************************************************")
        println("Overriding dependency ${details.requested.group}:${details.requested.name} version ${details.requested.version} --> $overrideVersion")
        details.useVersion overrideVersion
        println("********************************************************")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: EclipticWld Need help where to add this line plz tell me here is my {project_root}/android/build.gradle https://pastebin.com/Urr2QAvD

Comment: @Sunnynegi put `def versionOverrides` variable in root of `android/build.gradle` and `configurations.all` into `allprojects`

Comment: Like this https://pastebin.com/eHKSrRF4, After react-native run-android build is  failled

Comment: It should be 4.28, not 0.28. Thanks, btw, worked for me with the correct version number.

Comment: @EclipticWld Thank you so much it's works but will yo plz explain why i am facing this issue (real cause).

Comment: @Sunnynegi someone didn't set strict version of facebook-android-sdk in react-native-fbsdk library and when a new release comes it has new android api. 
ps. you could also set my answer as accepted :)

Comment: Same issue for android :( . And following your answer doesnt help

Comment: This fixed my issue. But if I understand correctly, even if having a fixed `react-native-fbsdk` version won't help, no? Since right now, I have mine as ^0.6.3.

Comment: @jpls93 I'm not sure when react-native-fbsdk team will fix it. Last time I was waiting for 3 weeks a new patch. They also have a complex approach to new updates and managing issues. Your version is fine with the current hot patch.

Comment: @Anuj seems like you're doing something wrong. Probably mistyped.

Comment: @EclipticWld Nope, but then i got it working by updating the build tools to 27

Comment: @Anuj interesting but I doubt is it correct solution based on the particular issue.

Comment: @EclipticWld For android, its best to use the latest build tools, and i had no restriction to work with a specific build tools version, so works for me!

Comment: Making this generic for a single override seems overkill. Just adding `configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
            }
        }` should be enough.

Answer (score 5):

Go to android level build gradle and add/update this line.

```
subprojects {
   afterEvaluate {project ->
       if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 25
            buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
        } 
       }
   }
}
```

to

```
subprojects {
afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 26
            buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
        }
    }
}
```

}

this solve my problem.

Comment: Suryakant Need help over this issue, plz tell me where to add this line, because i have no subprojects in my android level build

Comment: @Sunnynegi there wont be any you have to add it.

Comment: then what i have to do with your code, Plz enlighten me

Comment: Will this affect support for older versions of Android? There are multiple *SdkVersion properties, I'm not sure what does what.

Comment: @Sunnynegi All you have to do is go to android gradle and add this line subprojects {
afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 26
            buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
        }
    }
} } at bottom.

Comment: @AlexeyUkolov this might affect the older version of android... as there is regularly update on Android. so cant comment will if affect or not.

Comment: @Sunnynegi you might also have to add these lines maven {
              url "https://maven.google.com"
              name 'Google'
        }  in project Gradle file in allproject{ repositories{...

Answer (score 2):

I have been searching for the solution for hours and finally fixed it with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301203/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidkeyboardnavigationc)

You have to go to node-modules/react-native-fbsdk/android and changes `compilesdkVersion` to 26, `buildToolVersion` to 26.0.1, `targetsdkVersion` to 26 and finally `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+`

Comment: I tried you solution and it's working fine for me, but i have doubt that it is right to update the node-modules/react-native-fbsdk/android.

Answer (score 0):

While @EclipticWld's answer apparently works, it's a bit convoluted. Adding a single `force` is actually enough;

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ....
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[*Answer borrowed from a duplicate question*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47692414/189431)