# react-native-fb sdk com.android.support dependency error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

```
 > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fbsdk'.
  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-fbsdk:_debugPublishCopy'.
     > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
       Searched in the following locations:
           file:/<location_to_sdk>/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
           file:/<location_to_sdk>/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
           file:/<location_to_app>/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
       Required by:
           newPtMobile:react-native-fbsdk:unspecified
```

This issue started happening this morning when running react-native run-android without making any changes to the code or adding new packages, it was working fine untill now!

> "react-native":"0.50.3", "react-native-fbsdk":"0.6.3"

I can see that I am missing `android support libraries` in my `sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support` subfolders, all the subfolders have the `26.0.0-alpha1` folder as the last one.
I already tried removing support repository and installing again through android studio and downloading the latest `android_m2repository` manually but the folders are still missing.

What I am having trouble understanding is why `google's maven repository` (https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) states that under *for example* `m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7` I should have a folder named `27.0.2` (along with some previous versions which are also missing) but even in the latest android_m2repository which they offer it is also missing!

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r48.zip

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also have the same issue. I was able to successfully build by updating my
 **ROOT :** `android/build.gradle` file.

**STEPS :**
1. All you have to do is add a new `maven` line to the `allprojects` section for `maven.google.com`
2. Add `resolutionStrategy` Will Restrict your android fbsdk version to `4.28.0`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
        }
    }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thankyou, when i add https://maven.google.com , it download the missing items . but in my case, I also had to change my android/app/build.gradle and android/build.gradle to 26 , 27.0.2

Comment: Yes You Will have Update **Project : android/app/build.gradle and 
 all those Libraries which you LINK in your Project . FBSDK : android/build.gradle** to 26 , 27.0.2 @chii

Answer (score 6):

I see that another thread was open on this very same issue:  [getting error when run react-native run-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671206/getting-error-when-run-react-native-run-android#47689866)

The solution recommended there is close to Sutani one, that is editing `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle`
and adding

`compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0')`

It seems not to be a regression introduced by react-native-fbsdk but by Google Android libraries but I am not 100% clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem, and i solved with :

1. edit `package.json` and i am edit `react-native-fbsdk` from `react-native-fbsdk": "0.6.3"` to `react-native-fbsdk": "0.6.0"`
2. go to your `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle`. open `build.gradle file.`
3. Change `compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4++')` to `compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')`,

but I don't know if this is the best way for this problem, 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
CUR_SPACE=.
culpritLocation=$CUR_SPACE/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle

sed -i -e 's/com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+/com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0/' $culpritLocation

printf "Fixed Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-fbsdk:_debugPublishCopy'.\n> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1."
printf "fix_rn_fbsdk_google_libraries.sh should be removed at a later time\n"
```

Place the above script in the root of your react-native project, add executing permissions to it, then in package.json within the *postinstall* property add *./your-script-name.sh;*. Ex:

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "1.28.14",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "postinstall": "./fix_rn_fbsdk_google_libraries.sh; ./infuse_version.sh;"
  },
  [..]
}
```

If you're not familiar with postinstall scripts, they'll run immediately after running npm install / yarn command.

The proposed solution works with cloud build tools :) and it is only temporary. Future rn-fbsdk releases should fix the issue.

Comment: can you describe your answer more to make clear understanding.

Comment: As mentioned in the original comment, you'd have to create a file _your-script-name.sh_ in the root folder of the project, then add if not already using the _postinstall_ attribute in your package.json file. If the script has execution permission and the contents are the ones in the original answer it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the error message shown in your case:

> Searched in the following locations:
>   `file:/<location_to_sdk>/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/`

I have had the same. Then I went to the location:

> `file:<location_to_sdk>/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/`

And found that there is no directory named `27.0.1` because in my case the latest buildTool was not downloaded. In my case I have had `27.0.0-alpha1`.

So in both of my app `build.gradle` and in

> node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle

I replaced `27.0.1` with `27.0.0-alpha1` and build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

**build.gradle --- app**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+' // support react-native-v0.22-rc+
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy {
                    force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }


Solution:

How to fix the file permissions, after loading end react-native start

First, Go to android folder

cd android

Now clean the project...

gradlew clean //for Mac users, change gradlew to ./gradlew

Now run the build process again in the root folder 
cd ..
react-native run-android

Solved Issue Happy Coding!
```