# Cordova compile failed: Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am compiling my Cordova project at https://build.phonegap.com

It is giving me an error message:

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.

```
Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2.

 Required by:
     project :  com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0  com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.30.0
Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2.
 Required by:
     project :  com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0  com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.30.0
Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2.
 Required by:
     project :  com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0  com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.30.0
Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
 Required by:
     project :  com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0  com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.30.0
     project :  com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0  com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0
Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2.
 Required by:
     project :  com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0  com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.30.0
Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2.
 Required by:
     project :  com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0  com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.30.0
```

Please help. I am running on MacOS. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue; I'm not sure how to translate the solution provided from compiling from Android Studio here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47692414/859930

Comment: Same issue in command line cordova CLI.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and managed to resolve it.
As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671206/getting-error-when-run-react-native-run-android/47692414#47692414) the issue is caused by the facebook sdk.
If you run in cordova CLI you simply have to modify the platforms/android/project.properties.

Change this line:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
```

into this line:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0
```

As stated in the relative thread, this is a hack.