# Cordova build error: "Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy' > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2."

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, gradle, cordova-plugins

It's been now two days I'm fighting with this issue.

I'm trying to build a cordova project that built marvelously like 1 month ago.

In between these time periods I had to change my PC so I installed again Java, Android Studio and Cordova, setting it up as usual.

I installed Google Repository (v58) as well as Android Support Repository (v47.0.0) in the SDKManager. 
They appears to be the latest since I tried to uninstall and reinstall them twice.

I didn't change my project's configuration since I took a backup of it when it was working to start again.

When I run `cordova build android`, I got this error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Users/Pierrick/AppData/Local/Android1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Pierrick/AppData/Local/Android1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Pierrick/Desktop/hAz4rd0uS-uphair-1af95815ef72/hAz4rd0uS-uphair-1af95815ef72/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar

These files are needed by plugins cordova-plugin-mapbox (v1.2.3) and cordova-plugin-facebook4 (v1.9.1). Obviously, I checked the "extras" folder in my Android SDK directory, and the last version of Android support I got is 26.0.0-alpha1.

How can I manage to download the requested files in the good location ? 
Is it supposed to be done automatically ? 
I really don't see what I am missing here, some help would really be appreciated.

I tried to:

-Reinstall cordova-android by `cordova platform rm android` and `cordova platform add android@6.2.3`;

-Delete gradle's android support's cache and metadatas as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies);

-Reinstall Google repository and Android Support repository twice from Android Studio SDK Manager as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090248/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-appdebugapkcopy).

This is drivin' me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cam accross my problem and since I didn't see doublons of this thread I'm posting the answer here.
As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671206/getting-error-when-run-react-native-run-android/47692414#47692414) the issue is caused by the facebook sdk. If you run in cordova CLI you simply have to modify the platforms/android/project.properties file.

Change this line:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
```

into this line:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0
```

As stated in the relative thread, this is a hack.